# Filter Users In Table VC Based On UIPickerView Options

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3

Basically, I want users to be filtered in a Table View Controller, by the city they choose in a UIPickerView that is located in a View Controller.

I have already created an array in a regular View Controller that contains 5 options of cities to choose from. When they choose a city, that information is saved to Firebase. So for example, if 10 users pick "New York" from the UIPickerView, when they go to the Table View Controller- they can only see those same users who picked "New York" as well. What would be the best way to implement this? I can't seem to find the right resources to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see there are two possibilities based on need:

- If you fetch data from server, you can pass selected city to server as a parameter to fetch only those records that matches the required city.
- In case you have enough data at client end, you can use `NSPredicate` to keep the relevant city's data in a data source (say `filteredUsersInCity`) and load table view based on `filteredUsersInCity` data source.